# Why can't we use "%d" in C language instead of "%u" with pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

`%u` is used for unsigned numbers.
I get the same results if I use `%d` instead of `%u` to display the address of a variable.
We use `%u` just for ethics or does it make any real difference too.
Have a look:

```
int i=5;
printf("Address of i: %d", &i);
```

is same as:

```
printf("Again, address: %u" ,&i);
```

[EDIT] An example where it generates different output would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, I can't imagine a negative virtual address. And shouldn't you be using `%p`?

Comment: How do you print an address using `%d`? Aren't you print garbage value?

Comment: Am reading the book "Let us C" It used '%u' all the time

Comment: [Bad book](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Let+us+C%22), [full of errors](http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/Main_Page#Stuff_that_should_be_avoided). [Best avoided](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yashavant_Kanetkar).

Comment: The value of `&i` will vary as you compile/run the code.  It's not necessarily deterministic.

Comment: The results of either one are undefined by the C language standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `%d` will show a negative value for addresses with the most significant bit set (high addresses)
- `%u` will always show the positive interpretation of the bits
- `%p` is the best, since it's explicitly reserved for printing addresses.

Consider this, supposing an address of `0xffffffff`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    void* val = 0xffffffff;

    printf("d = %d\n", val);
    printf("u = %u\n", val);
    printf("p = %p\n", val);

    return 0;
}
```

And, it's output:

```
d = -1
u = 4294967295
p = 0xffffffff
```

Comment: No, `%d` and `%u` are just utterly wrong.

Answer (score 7):

You can cross the street without looking both ways many times and you might not get hit by a car. That doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: At least with your example, you probably won't live to tell the tale... with the program, you may be stuck debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, even `"%u"` is wrong; for pointers you have to use `"%p"`

---

Still, `%d`-instead-of-`%u` works because on your architecture signed and unsigned numbers have the same *representation* as far as we are looking at positive numbers. So, if you pass a pointer to `%d`, `printf` will try to interpreter the parameter as a signed integer, and you'll get the same result of `%u` as long as the high bit of the pointer is not set (which is usually the norm for user-mode pointers); otherwise, you'll get a negative number with `%d` and a positive one with `%u` (assuming your machine employs 2's complement arithmetic).

Interestingly, the biggest error is not mismatching the signedness, but using integer specificators (`%d` and `%u`) instead of the pointer specificator (`%p`); in facts, on most 64 bit architectures `int` is 32 bit, but `void *` is 64 bit, thus using `%u` instead of `%p` will only print half of the address (the lower half on little-endian architectures, like x86_64).

Notice: all this explanation comes from "typical implementations" of the C language; as far as the standard is concerned, if you mismatch the type of the format specificator and of the actual data you go into "undefined behavior" (=anything from a crash to pink unicorns flying out of your printer).

Comment: Not just the same representation - in fact, I would argue that integers and pointers can *never* have the same representation since their sets of possible *values* have empty intersection - but the same size and argument-passing convention is what matters.

Answer (score 2):

When printing pointers in C, you should use `%p`, not `%u` or `%d`. `%u` and `%d` are intended to display integer values. You are implicitly casting your pointers to integers when you use those flags to print out pointers and there are quite a few architectures were this can cause a lot of trouble (especially in 64bit architectures).

The difference between `%d` and `%u` is like you mentioned, `%u` treats the value as unsigned and `%d` as signed. The results will be different if the highest order bit is 1. You can see this easily when using -1.

```
printf("%d, %u\n", -1, -1);
```

Output:

```
-1,4294967295
```

Answer (score 0):

There are unusual CPU architectures where a pointer has a different representation or size than an unsigned number.

One common example is 32-bit x86 code written in segmented mode, where an address consists of a 16-bit segment number with a 32-bit segment offset. (Disclaimer: it's been years since I looked at this, so I may have forgotten the details.)

Another case is a 64-bit machine set up to use 64-bit pointers, and 32-bit ints.